# Sqlite DB querying takes a long time WP8

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am building a Windows Phone 8 app using sqlite.net using this link as a reference:-

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone

There is a database in the project which is being seeded in the Isolated Storage. The database contains only one table which has almost 26k entries.

I am trying to connect to that database in my MainPage.xaml.cs as follows:-

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    using (SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(App._dbPath))
    {
        db.GetTableInfo("IWMCemeteries");
        try
        {
            List<IWMCemeteries> cemeteriesList = db.Table<IWMCemeteries>().ToList<IWMCemeteries>();
             MessageBox.Show("Number of elements in table is " + cemeteriesList.Count);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it takes too long(over 25 seconds) for the message dialog to show up.

I tried an alternate method running a raw query as follows:-

```
List<IWMCemeteries> cemeteries = db.Query<IWMCemeteries>("select * from IWMCemeteries");
MessageBox.Show("Number of elements in list is " + cemeteries.Count);
```

But this seems to take even longer!(almost 30s).

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Rajeev

Comment: Why are you loading the 26,000 elements in memory if all you want is to display the count of them? i.e. `select count(*) from IWMCemeteries`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The count statement is just a test. I will actually need all the data inside the app. Is there anyway to optimize the query/database?

Comment: Do not load 26,000 instances of classes in memory on a mobile device, re-think your app design.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will change the design to fetch the data only when I need it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong here for me. As some people noticed, with 26k rows you are starting to work with an interesting bulk of data. So, in mobile devices working with a "lite" database, you must adapt your request depending on what you really need :

- You want the number of rows, then use SELECT COUNT(*)
- You want to display all rows in a list, then use paging or asynchronous loading (on scroll down) to fetch only 20 elements each times.

In any apps, but mostly in mobile devices, you have to consider the volume of data which moves.

In this way, any request would be instant and your application will perform well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will change the app design to fetch only the data that I need

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your query. Just limit the data you fetch from the database. It's a mobile device with limited power, not a full blown pc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The count statement is just a test. I will actually need all the data inside the app. Is there anyway to optimize the query/database?

Comment: No since its only one table, no relationships that make the query "heavier". You could take a thousand records each time, then when the user scrolls to the bottom of the control you display your data, take the next thousand. Thats the only way to go if you want to work with/display all the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will implement incremental loading in the app where I need lots of data