# WP8 SQlite Select Query

Tags: sql, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I have following code.

```
string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Questions.sqlite");
SQLiteConnection dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH);
dbConn.CreateTable<QuestionModel>();

// Some code which insert the records in database from webservices.

List<QuestionModel> questionsList = dbConn.Table<QuestionModel>().ToList();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("List Count " + dbConn.Table<QuestionModel>().ToList().Count);
```

The List Count gives me **0** always. But When I use **WP POWER TOOLS** and get the **Questions.sqlite** file from emulator. It gives me records in SQLite table.

I also check the query in http://sqlitestudio.pl/ on the same **Questions.sqlite** but that gives me records as it should.

I tried other way to get the records as following code but none them were working.

```
String query = "Select * from QuestionModel;";
questionsList = dbConn.Query<QuestionModel>(query);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("List Count " + questionsList.Count);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your analysis seems like only the row `List<QuestionModel> questionsList = dbConn.Table<QuestionModel>().ToList();` is not working.
I helped someone in SQLiteDB on WP8 a couple of days ago, here is his question : [SQLite WP8 StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22893611/3503205)

If you compare his code with your code, you are missing the Model bindind  :

```
db.GetTableInfo("QuestionModel");
```

And

```
db.Table<QuestionModel>().ToList<QuestionModel>();
```

Not important but use your list variable to get count in debug write to not retrieve twice the list `questionsList.Count`

Hope it helps.